# HDHomeRun Dual and Kaffeine

Tags: 12.10, apt, dpkg, tv

I am trying to get HDHomeRun Dual to work with Kaffeine. I installed DVB per the instructions here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/dvbhdhomerun/wiki/UbuntuPackages

but at the end, when I install, I get the following error:

```
Setting up dvbhdhomerun-utils (0.0.13-1) ...

start: Job failed to start

invoke-rc.d: initscript dvbhdhomerun-utils, action "start" failed.

dpkg: error processing dvbhdhomerun-utils (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

 dvbhdhomerun-utils

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've been searching and I believe it has to do with DVB_core, but I cant seem to find a solution.  I'm running 12.10.  Truth be told, outside of excel, my last bout with programming was Basic...many, many (many) years ago, so I'm a bit of a noob with this.

Thanks for any help

Comment: 'dvbhdhomerun' has moved to here: https://github.com/h0tw1r3/dvbhdhomerun